# What can cause focus to be set in Access 2010/VBA, other than SetFocus?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, setfocus

I have a continuous subform that takes its data from one of two queries dependent on the value of a string.

With the first query, the focus is set on the first text box (Prospect_Name) of the first row, as expected. I don't use SetFocus to set the focus here, this is what it chooses authomatically.

With the second, the focus is set on a different text box of the first row (ID), which is causing me all sorts of problems - I don't have horizontal scrollbars on, and this menu is meant to be "offscreeen", but if focus is set to it, the subform automatically scrolls to that value. Focus is always set to that text box. It's not last one horizontally, or anything like that.

I've checked and there's no SetFocus to move the focus to ID, so why would it be doing it? I assume it must be something to do with the second query as that's the only thing that's changed? The second query is a union query, could that be to blame?

Queries below, though they're a bit long so I don't know how much help they'll be.

Working query:

```
SELECT Prospects.ID, Prospects.Company, Prospects.[Registered No], Prospects.[Limited Company], Prospects.[Originally Known As], Prospects.Office AS [BF Office], Prospects.Partner, Prospects.Partner2, Prospects.Partner3, Prospects.Status, Prospects.[SIC Code], Prospects.TPSMPS, Prospects.Website, Prospects.Sector, Prospects.[Turnover Bracket], Prospects.Turnover, Prospects.[Turnover Min], Prospects.[Turnover Max], Prospects.Accountant, Prospects.Bank, Prospects.Solicitor, Prospects.Employees, Prospects.[Audit Fee], Prospects.CharityType, Prospects.Sourceoffinancials, Prospects.DateCreated, Prospects.Createby, Prospects.DateModified, Prospects.Modifiedby, Prospects.[Key Contact], Prospects.[Address Type], Prospects.Address1, Prospects.Address2, Prospects.Address3, Prospects.Town, Prospects.County, Prospects.Postcode, Prospects.[Telephone Number], Prospects.Email, Prospects.[Incorrect Emails], Prospects.Telemarket, Prospects.Sourceofdata, Prospects.Clientcode, Prospects.DateConverted, Prospects.[Number of Beds in Group], Prospects.[Number of Homes in Group], Prospects.[Healthcare Type], Prospects.CharitiesT, Prospects.WManagementT, Prospects.CareT, Prospects.PropertyT, Prospects.LeisureTourismT, Prospects.MarineT, Prospects.MediaCreativeT, Prospects.ProPracticesT, Prospects.MotorT, Prospects.PersonalTaxT, Prospects.TaxT, Prospects.VATT, Prospects.PayrollT, Prospects.AuditT, Prospects.SAGET, Prospects.AccountsT, Prospects.CFinT, Prospects.BusinessRecoveryT, Prospects.ForensicT, Prospects.GrantT, Prospects.IFAT, Prospects.IntTaxT, Prospects.TaxInvT, Prospects.RenewablesT, Prospects.AcademiesT, Prospects.MTIT, [Prospects]![NextContact] AS NextContactA, Nz([NextContact],"~") AS NextContactNZ, Nz([Key Contacts]![Last Name],"zz") AS KeyContact1NZ, Nz([Key Contacts]![First Name],"~") AS KeyContact2NZ, Nz([Most Recent Contact]![SortA],"zz") AS DateNZ, [Most Recent Contact.SortA] AS DateA, [Most Recent Contact].Information AS [Note Full Info], [Key Contacts].[First Name], Prospects.[Holding Company], Prospects.[TPS/CTPS], Prospects.[Top 500], Prospects.NextContact, Prospects.[Payroll Status], [Key Contacts].[Key Contact E-Mail], [Key Contacts].[Key Contact], [Most Recent Contact].*, [Date] & IIf([Date] Is Not Null,": ","") & [Title] AS [Note Information], "N/A" AS [Filter Checker], Prospects.Company AS [Group], "Parent" AS [Parent / Child], [Most Recent Contact].[Added by] AS [Note author], Nz(Right((Left([NextContactA],10)),4) & Mid([NextContactA],4,2) & Left([NextContactA],2),"zz") AS NextContactSortA
    FROM ((Prospects LEFT JOIN [Key Contacts] ON Prospects.ID = [Key Contacts].ID) LEFT JOIN [Most Recent Contact] ON Prospects.ID = [Most Recent Contact].[Prospect ID]) INNER JOIN [Report - Holding Filter] ON Prospects.ID = [Report - Holding Filter].ID
    WHERE (((Prospects.Status) Not Like "Duplicate") AND ((Prospects.Company) Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Search Text] & "*"))
    ORDER BY Prospects.Company;
```

Query that's causing an issue:

```
SELECT * FROM [SearchByName] UNION SELECT * FROM [SearchByName - GrandChildren];
```

The first part of that query (SearchByName) is the previous query, the second part is below:

```
SELECT * FROM [SearchByName - Holding Companies] UNION SELECT * FROM [SearchByName - Level 1 subsidiaries];
```

Which is itself made up of the following two queries:

```
SELECT [SearchByName - No Filter].ID, [SearchByName - No Filter].Company, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Registered No], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Limited Company], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Originally Known As], [SearchByName - No Filter].[BF Office], [SearchByName - No Filter].Partner, [SearchByName - No Filter].Partner2, [SearchByName - No Filter].Partner3, [SearchByName - No Filter].Status, [SearchByName - No Filter].[SIC Code], [SearchByName - No Filter].TPSMPS, [SearchByName - No Filter].Website, [SearchByName - No Filter].Sector, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Turnover Bracket], [SearchByName - No Filter].Turnover, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Turnover Min], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Turnover Max], [SearchByName - No Filter].Accountant, [SearchByName - No Filter].Bank, [SearchByName - No Filter].Solicitor, [SearchByName - No Filter].Employees, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Audit Fee], [SearchByName - No Filter].CharityType, [SearchByName - No Filter].Sourceoffinancials, [SearchByName - No Filter].DateCreated, [SearchByName - No Filter].Createby, [SearchByName - No Filter].DateModified, [SearchByName - No Filter].Modifiedby, [SearchByName - No Filter].Prospects.[Key Contact], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Address Type], [SearchByName - No Filter].Address1, [SearchByName - No Filter].Address2, [SearchByName - No Filter].Address3, [SearchByName - No Filter].Town, [SearchByName - No Filter].County, [SearchByName - No Filter].Postcode, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Telephone Number], [SearchByName - No Filter].Email, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Incorrect Emails], [SearchByName - No Filter].Telemarket, [SearchByName - No Filter].Sourceofdata, [SearchByName - No Filter].Clientcode, [SearchByName - No Filter].DateConverted, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Number of Beds in Group], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Number of Homes in Group], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Healthcare Type], [SearchByName - No Filter].CharitiesT, [SearchByName - No Filter].WManagementT, [SearchByName - No Filter].CareT, [SearchByName - No Filter].PropertyT, [SearchByName - No Filter].LeisureTourismT, [SearchByName - No Filter].MarineT, [SearchByName - No Filter].MediaCreativeT, [SearchByName - No Filter].ProPracticesT, [SearchByName - No Filter].MotorT, [SearchByName - No Filter].PersonalTaxT, [SearchByName - No Filter].TaxT, [SearchByName - No Filter].VATT, [SearchByName - No Filter].PayrollT, [SearchByName - No Filter].AuditT, [SearchByName - No Filter].SAGET, [SearchByName - No Filter].AccountsT, [SearchByName - No Filter].CFinT, [SearchByName - No Filter].BusinessRecoveryT, [SearchByName - No Filter].ForensicT, [SearchByName - No Filter].GrantT, [SearchByName - No Filter].IFAT, [SearchByName - No Filter].IntTaxT, [SearchByName - No Filter].TaxInvT, [SearchByName - No Filter].RenewablesT, [SearchByName - No Filter].AcademiesT, [SearchByName - No Filter].MTIT, [SearchByName - No Filter].NextContactA, [SearchByName - No Filter].NextContactNZ, [SearchByName - No Filter].KeyContact1NZ, [SearchByName - No Filter].KeyContact2NZ, [SearchByName - No Filter].DateNZ, [SearchByName - No Filter].DateA, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Note Full Info], [SearchByName - No Filter].[First Name], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Holding Company], [SearchByName - No Filter].[TPS/CTPS], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Top 500], [SearchByName - No Filter].NextContact, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Payroll Status], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Key Contact E-Mail], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Key Contacts].[Key Contact], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Lead ID], [SearchByName - No Filter].Information, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Prospect ID], [SearchByName - No Filter].Title, [SearchByName - No Filter].Date, [SearchByName - No Filter].Hyperlink, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Added by], [SearchByName - No Filter].SortA, [SearchByName - No Filter].[Note Information], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Filter Checker], [SearchByName - No Filter].Group, "Parent" AS [Parent / Child], [SearchByName - No Filter].[Added by] AS [Note Author], " " AS [Intentionally blank]
FROM [SearchByName - No Filter] INNER JOIN [SearchByName - Level 1 Subsidiaries] ON [SearchByName - No Filter].ID = [SearchByName - Level 1 Subsidiaries].[Holding Company];
```

and

```
SELECT [SearchByName - No filter].ID, "     " & [Subsidiaries]![Company] & " (subsidiary of " & [SearchByName - No Filter]![Company] & ")" AS Company, Subsidiaries.[Registered No], [SearchByName - No filter].[Limited Company], [SearchByName - No filter].[Originally Known As], [SearchByName - No filter].[BF Office], [SearchByName - No filter].Partner, [SearchByName - No filter].Partner2, [SearchByName - No filter].Partner3, [SearchByName - No filter].Status, [SearchByName - No filter].[SIC Code], [SearchByName - No filter].TPSMPS, [SearchByName - No filter].Website, [SearchByName - No filter].Sector, [SearchByName - No filter].[Turnover Bracket], [SearchByName - No filter].Turnover, [SearchByName - No filter].[Turnover Min], [SearchByName - No filter].[Turnover Max], [SearchByName - No filter].Accountant, [SearchByName - No filter].Bank, [SearchByName - No filter].Solicitor, [SearchByName - No filter].Employees, [SearchByName - No filter].[Audit Fee], [SearchByName - No filter].CharityType, [SearchByName - No filter].Sourceoffinancials, [SearchByName - No filter].DateCreated, [SearchByName - No filter].Createby, [SearchByName - No filter].DateModified, [SearchByName - No filter].Modifiedby, [SearchByName - No filter].Prospects.[Key Contact], [SearchByName - No filter].[Address Type], [SearchByName - No filter].Address1, [SearchByName - No filter].Address2, [SearchByName - No filter].Address3, [SearchByName - No filter].Town, [SearchByName - No filter].County, [SearchByName - No filter].Postcode, [SearchByName - No filter].[Telephone Number], [SearchByName - No filter].Email, [SearchByName - No filter].[Incorrect Emails], [SearchByName - No filter].Telemarket, [SearchByName - No filter].Sourceofdata, [SearchByName - No filter].Clientcode, [SearchByName - No filter].DateConverted, [SearchByName - No filter].[Number of Beds in Group], [SearchByName - No filter].[Number of Homes in Group], [SearchByName - No filter].[Healthcare Type], [SearchByName - No filter].CharitiesT, [SearchByName - No filter].WManagementT, [SearchByName - No filter].CareT, [SearchByName - No filter].PropertyT, [SearchByName - No filter].LeisureTourismT, [SearchByName - No filter].MarineT, [SearchByName - No filter].MediaCreativeT, [SearchByName - No filter].ProPracticesT, [SearchByName - No filter].MotorT, [SearchByName - No filter].PersonalTaxT, [SearchByName - No filter].TaxT, [SearchByName - No filter].VATT, [SearchByName - No filter].PayrollT, [SearchByName - No filter].AuditT, [SearchByName - No filter].SAGET, [SearchByName - No filter].AccountsT, [SearchByName - No filter].CFinT, [SearchByName - No filter].BusinessRecoveryT, [SearchByName - No filter].ForensicT, [SearchByName - No filter].GrantT, [SearchByName - No filter].IFAT, [SearchByName - No filter].IntTaxT, [SearchByName - No filter].TaxInvT, [SearchByName - No filter].RenewablesT, [SearchByName - No filter].AcademiesT, [SearchByName - No filter].MTIT, [SearchByName - No filter].NextContactA, [SearchByName - No filter].NextContactNZ, [SearchByName - No filter].KeyContact1NZ, [SearchByName - No filter].KeyContact2NZ, [SearchByName - No filter].DateNZ, [SearchByName - No filter].DateA, [SearchByName - No filter].[Note Full Info], [SearchByName - No filter].[First Name], Subsidiaries.[Holding Company], [SearchByName - No filter].[TPS/CTPS], [SearchByName - No filter].[Top 500], [SearchByName - No filter].NextContact, [SearchByName - No filter].[Payroll Status], [SearchByName - No filter].[Key Contact E-Mail], [SearchByName - No filter].[Key Contacts].[Key Contact], [SearchByName - No filter].[Lead ID], [SearchByName - No filter].Information, [SearchByName - No filter].[Prospect ID], [SearchByName - No filter].Title, [SearchByName - No filter].Date, [SearchByName - No filter].Hyperlink, [SearchByName - No filter].[Added by], [SearchByName - No filter].SortA, [SearchByName - No filter].[Note Information], [SearchByName - No filter].[Filter Checker], [SearchByName - No filter].Group, "Child" AS [Parent / Child], [SearchByName - No filter].[Added by] AS [Note Author], " " AS [Intentionally blank]
FROM Prospects AS Subsidiaries INNER JOIN [SearchByName - No filter] ON Subsidiaries.[Holding Company] = [SearchByName - No filter].ID
WHERE ((("     " & [Subsidiaries]![Company] & " (subsidiary of " & [SearchByName - No Filter]![Company] & ")") Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Search Text] & "*"));
```

Comment: Does it help to set Visible = No on the ID text box?

Comment: Why not just set the focus yourself in the form current event?

Comment: I don't understand your statement "...continuous subform that takes its data from one of two queries dependent on the value of a string." You have a subform, and this has a record source, which is a query or some sort, be it an sql statement written into the recordsource property, or the name of a query. Therefore the subform is powered by a single query, regardless of the number of component statements comprising that query. Please explain how a string is involved here. Do you have a current event that is doing something and not working as expected? If so, post your code.

Comment: To answer the title of your post, Tab order & Docmd.GotoControl can both impact on focus.

Comment: And the winner is @HansUp - if you want to pop that in as an answer, I'll happily accept it; no idea why it's happening but as long as it works I'm not overly concerned.

Comment: @engineersmnky, tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: @JohnBingham Thanks, I'll look into the code now that I have a solution and see if that was what was causing the problem in the first place. Regarding the string bit, the RecordSource changes to the name of the string on loading.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin  I did it.  That doesn't answer the title question, but if you're OK, I'm OK too.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp - it solves the problem, and will probably solve the same problem for anyone who gets here via Google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is a result of Access setting focus on a text box which you don't want displayed anyway, hide that text box by setting its `Visible` property to `No`.  Access can't set focus to a hidden field.

Comment: Just for anyone who lands here if you want to show the fields but do not want the focus to be able to be set you can also change the `enabled` property to `false` which will have the same effect because access cannot set focus on a disabled field either.